# Spring WebFlux - FilePart forward via webClient

Tags: spring-webflux, multipartform-data, spring-webclient

I went through similar tickets (i.e. [How to stream file from Multipart/form-data in Spring WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408075/how-to-stream-file-from-multipart-form-data-in-spring-webflux)), but apparently I have slightly different case.

High-level example (*no error handling / no 'empty' checks*):

Controller:

```java
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> create(
        @RequestPart(value = "images", required = false) final Flux<FilePart> images
    ) {
        ...service-call...
    }
```

Service:

```java
    public Mono<String> create(
        final Flux<FilePart> images
    ) {
        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();

        return images
            .filter(part -> Objects.nonNull(part.headers().getContentType()))
            .filter(part ->
                part.headers().getContentType().includes(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                    || part.headers().getContentType().includes(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
            )
            .doOnNext(
                part -> builder
                        .asyncPart("images", part.content(), DataBuffer.class)
                        .filename(part.filename())
            )
            .then(webClient.post()
                .uri(URI_RESOURCE)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
            );
    }
```

the problem is, client does not receive actual "images" :( I added some `doOnNext` to log the fact that files are added to builder, so I know they are.

I assume it is because of `.asyncPart("images", part.content(), DataBuffer.class)` but not sure how to avoid / bypass this internal publisher?

As a note, controller expects a `Flux` based on all recommendations I saw; however switching to plain `List<FilePart>`, solves the problem, while I think it is an anti-pattern to assume "blocking" request in WebFlux, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `then(webClient...)` block is already called and MultipartBodyBuilder.build() is executed at the start of the request. You can wrap `then` part with `Mono.defer`.

```
               ...
               .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
                    return webClient.post()
                            .uri(URI_RESOURCE)
                            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(String.class);
                }));
```

Comment: oh, wow, how silly I was :/ your solution works like a charm, thank you! :)

I was confused by the javadoc:
Let this Flux complete >then< play signals from a provided Mono.
In other words ignore element from this Flux and transform its completion signal into the >emission and completion< signal of a provided Mono<V>